# How to change color of Navigation controller back button?

Tags: ios, iphone, uikit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O01zg.png)

How can i change this button's color and its title programatically?

This is how i push my controller:

```
let controller = LoginController()
navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside `viewDidLoad` of `LoginController()`
please assign respective `tintColor` to the UIBarButtonItem

```
let leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(xxx)
leftBarButtonItem.tintColor = #UIColor
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButtonItem
```